# Loss of data when read xlsx as multipart/form-data

Tags: mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am sending an xlsx file via post request as multipart/form-data to a HTTP listener when I check the size of the payload by using

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.^
```

The content length is shown as 35Kb. Please find below:
[image]
but when I copy the payload to a temporary variable and I check the size of the temporary variable the content length is shown as 19KB. Please find below:
[image]
and I can see that there is loss of data in the variable.

I have used this script to copy data from payload to temp payload (vars.tempPayload):

```
%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data 
---
payload
```

Why is this happening, Can anyone please help me with this. How to retain the entire content of the multipart/form-data payload ?

Comment: Did you mean payload.^raw instead of payload.^ ?

Comment: @SalimKhan No, there are lot of options using payload.^, payload.^raw is one of them. It will show the properties of the payload using payload.^

Comment: Please log payload.^ and add the output to the question

Comment: What i meant was using sizeOf(payload.^raw)

Comment: @AmerSufi, Can you please share the expression that you have used for setting the value into the temporary variable? I tried replicating what you mentioned, but I was getting the same size in both payload and the temporary variable.

Comment: [@TheOtherGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8999743/theotherguy) I have added the script and detailed images.

Comment: Thanks @AmerSufi.Couple of things:                                                                  
1.Why is the mediatype application/json(as in screenshot),if you are just dealing with multipart/form-data?Are there any other transformations involved?
2.Do you conclude that there is loss of data just by looking at the 'content-length' value?Please log both the sizeOf payload.^raw and vars.tempPayload.^raw and let us know what you observe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used the payload.parts.file.content.^raw and copied it to another variable, there was no data loss.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are looking at the content-length for the entire request, not for the specific attachment that you are interested at.